# psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have setup a Ubuntu VPS as per the railcast episode #335. I've worked through a few issues but can't get past the error above when starting Unicorn. I have been testing with this command to connect to the db since.

```
psql -U postgres -W
```

I have edited /etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf as follows

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all         postgres                          trust   

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust   
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust   
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

It doesn't seem to matter what METHOD I use (trust, md5, password) the error is the same.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `psql -U postgres -h localhost`

Comment: Looks like I was testing with the wrong command, when I tried the above everything works. bundle exec unicorn -E production -c config/unicorn.rb also now starts the server. Thanks for the push in the right direction.
I'm now getting a 502 Bad Gateway from nginx... on to the next error!

Answer (score 0):

As Per my setting plz use below setting can help this setting dear...

> host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
>
> host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
>
> host all all ::1/128 md5

Answer (score 0):

You usually connect as the `postgres` user with `sudo -u postgres psql`. Note that `sudo` prompts for the current users password (unless you are root), not a user from the database.